# Android internal Storage Possibilities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am making an android application that needs only one time log in in its lifetime until user uninstall it.And what i mean by this is, it remember user name and password just like whats app do. This is what i have tried so far..

```
SharedPreferences prefer = getSharedPreferences("typeOfUser",0);
String x = prefer.getString("xyz","");

if(xyz.equals("")){
    // do move to login page
else 
     // do not move to login page
```

Is it the best way to do it. Tell me the best way and also what are the disadvantages of this.

Comment: hi the answer is updated hope will be helpful to you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes SharedPreferences will be best suited for yours application to achieve one time login. what you need to do is you nee to store values  in SharedPreferences and later you can check with the logic, create a util class as follows :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Utils {

    public static void savePreferences(Activity activity, String key1,
            String value1, String key2, String value2) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getApplicationContext());
        Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.putString(key1, value1);
        editor.putString(key2, value2);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String readPreferences(Activity activity, String key,
            String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getApplicationContext());
        return sp.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

and finally we can use it as follows

```
Utils.savePreferences(MainActivity.this, "username", userNameValue,
                "password", passwordValue);
```

and to fetch the data

```
Utils.readPreferences(MainActivity.this, "username", "default username");

Utils.readPreferences(MainActivity.this, "password",
                        "default password");
```

beside this as you know  you can use defaul sharedpreferences as

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

rather than doing above what you can do is  give explicitly named sharedpreferences with a given mode

```
SharedPreferences sp = activity.getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences("SomePref", activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In my opinion this a good way to achieve one time login!! and disadvantage is that if someone will **clear the data** of the app than values will be vanished , however hope  it will not be a big issue for you.

**Note:** you can do necessary changes according to yours need in Util class with respect to logic.

download the complete example exactly what you are expecting from

**https://github.com/junal/Android-SharedPreferences**

**https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences**